# Webcam not opening in secondary Python process (macOS Catalina)

Tags: python, opencv, macos-catalina, webcam-capture

I have recently upgraded my MacBook to run Catalina. This seems to have broken webcam access to secondary processes.

The following code ran like a charm on Mojave but won't let me access the webcam in the secondary process.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from multiprocessing import Process

import cv2

def capture_cam(process):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    (ret, frame) = cap.read()
    print(process, ret)

p_cam = Process(target=capture_cam, args=['Secondary'])
p_cam.start()

p_cam.join()
capture_cam('Primary')
```

The output under Catalina is

```sh
$ export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
$ python test.py
Primary True
```

The problem is very curious to me. I guess it has something to do with the new privacy settings in 10.15.